# HashMap JSON object sent to browser through AJAX prints as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax, hashmap

I am getting this strange issue here. I am sending a HashMap as a JSON to client side through AJAX to populate a dropdown. Everything looks good on server side but on the client side browser, the dropdown is being populated as [object Object]. What am I missing? My code is as follows.

```
 HashMap<Integer, Cars> cars = new HashMap();
 cars.put(1,car1);
 cars.put(2,car2);
 json = new Gson().toJson(cars);
 System.out.println(json); // PRINTS WELL
 try {
            ServletOutputStream os = res.getOutputStream();                
            os.write(json.toString().getBytes());
            flushCloseOutputStream(os);
            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("from catch");
            res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Cannot create response");
        }
        setDestination(req, RESPONSE_NO_REDIRECT);
```

On the client side

```
function populatedd(dropdown){
.....
.....
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {   
   var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
   dropdown.options.length = 0;
   for (var key in jsonResponse) {
                createOption(dropdown, jsonResponse[key], key);
            }

.....
.....}

  function createOption(dropdown, text, value) {
    var x = document.createElement('option');
    x.value = value;
    x.text = text;
    dropdown.options.add(x);
}
```

P.S. no jQuery

Comment: `function createOption(dropdown, text, value) {` what are the values of `dropdown`, `text`, and `value`?

Comment: I'd bet that your text isn't a string but an object. Try to console.log the value of text in the createOption function

Comment: @WilliamKLEIN .. you are right..